# How to join Prometheus queries to gain their aggregate results

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to join two promql queries to gain their results but faced some troubles. We have two metrics:

- http_server_requests_total - counter for requests. Labels: app, path, method, response_status_code. Produces a integer number of requests.
- http_server_request_duration_seconds_bucket - histogram to measure response time from http requests. Labels also: app, path, method, response_status_code. Use "le" label to sort time series over buckets.

I have two queries for these metrics:

**endpoints with highest number of requests**

```
topk(40, 
    sum(http_server_requests_total{app=~"web_api_service", response_status_code=~"2..|4..|5.."}) 
        by (app, path, method, response_status_code)
)
```

**endpoints with highest execution time**

```
histogram_quantile(
  0.95,
  sum by (le, app, path, method, response_status_code) 
      (rate(http_server_request_duration_seconds_bucket{
          app=~"web_api_service",response_status_code=~"2..|4..|5.."
      }[$__rate_interval]))
)
```

Now I want to combine results of these two queries to examine slowest endpoints with highest number of requests. I've tried several methods from this [article](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/prometheus-vector-matching/) to join queries:

- simple `and` between two queries gives me number of requests from the first query as a Value (I run these queries in Grafana Explore tab since we have no direct access to Prometheus server).
- same result for `+` or `+ on(app, path, method, response_status_code)` or `+ on(app, path, method, response_status_code) group_left`. Also I get only number of requests as Value (and NaN also).
- `+ on(app, path, method, response_status_code, le) group_right` returns slightly different results. But still there are no float `le` values of request duration from the second metric.

My questions are:

- what is a correct way to join results of two metrics to gain intersection of number of requests and requests duration?
- how can I make similar to sql `ORDER BY first_metric, second_metric DESC` in the promql?

Comment: so clarify, do you want "95p for top 40 most frequent requests"?

Comment: @star67 Yes. I could also play with this value to increase the intersection like: find the slowest queries in 100 most heavy-called endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vector matching

So you need to combine the results of two PromQL queries into one, f.e. [**topk**](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) aggregation and [**histogram_quantile()**](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile) function, to get something like *"a latency of N most frequent requests"*.

The right way to combine metrics in PromQL is *vector matching*, that might be *one-to-one* or *many-to-one* depending on labels matching.

The first query returns N most frequent requests:

```
topk(40, sum(http_server_requests_total{}) by(app, path, method, response_status_code))
```

The second query returns a latency:

```
histogram_quantile(
  0.95,
  sum(rate(http_server_request_duration_seconds_bucket{}[1m])) by(le, app, path, method, response_status_code)
)
```

But how to combine them? You have 2 vectors with equal labels (due to **by()** clause on the same labels) so it's *one-to-one* vector matching.

The result value (95p latency) is provided by the 2nd query, so the trick here is to discard the 1st value. You could achieve this by making the 1st value equal to `1` and by multiplying the `1` to the 2nd value. How to make it a `1`? Any number in a power of `0` returns `1`, and Prometheus does support [**arithmetic operations**](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators):

```
topk(40, sum(http_server_requests_total{}) by(app, path, method, response_status_code)) ^ 0
*
histogram_quantile(
  0.95,
  sum(rate(http_server_request_duration_seconds_bucket{}[1m])) by(le, app, path, method, response_status_code)
)
```

### sort(), sort_desc()

To get results sorted you could use one of the sorting queries either on final or one of sub-results.

**topK** returns already sorted results in descending order, so you could just sort the final latency vector:

```
sort_desc(
  topk(40, sum(http_server_requests_total{}) by(app, path, method, 
  response_status_code)) ^ 0
  *
  histogram_quantile(
    0.95,
    sum(rate(http_server_request_duration_seconds_bucket{}[1m])) by(le, app, 
  path, method, response_status_code)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! This query works. If you want to get latest values in the Grafana, you need to set (in the query Options) Format -> Table and Type -> Instant. 
@star67 Am I right that vector matching in the PromQL will produce one value in any case (that's why you suggested a trick with power of 0 for the 1-st vector Value) and there are no possibility to get results of both queries in joining (like in SQL)?

Comment: afaik 1 metric has 1 value. If you want two values (both count and latency) on the same metric -- you could use additional tricks to make one of them as a label. However most probably you don't want it, but just put two queries on the same graph

Comment: If my first comment is correct, it seems that vector matching with * (and 1 as a result of first query) will not give us a two queries results intersection. It will be a multiplication the result of second query on 1 from the first. So, it seems just like a result of second query in the end.

Comment: And if my second comment is correct, then the result of the intersection should looks like:
sort_desc(query2 and query1) - this will intersect both sets but put a duration from a second as a query value.

Comment: metric1 returns "count", metric2 returns "latency" -- what do you mean by metric3 as "intersection"? you provided SQL join analogy, but the join assumes there're 2 values in result (column1 and column2). Vector matching is more like aggregation (`sum`/`max`/`avg`) in SQL terms

Comment: I meant "intersection" with "and" as Vienne diagram's analogy from here https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/prometheus-vector-matching/#many-to-many-vector-matching-logicalset-operations

Comment: it depends on labels -- in your particular case the labels are identical -- 1. you operate on counters provided by `Histogram`, 2. you use equal labels in both `topK` and `histogram_quantile` aggregation. So it's 1-to-1 matching. You just don't have to deal with multiple matches here to use `and`/`unless`/`or`